# How to update global custom user properties in Google Analytics 4 [GA4]?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

With Google Analytics 4 [GA4] it's possible to [add custom user properties](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095?hl=en) to each event.

> 6. Optional: Add any custom user properties that you'd like to configure in User Properties.

This is explained further in [[GA4] About event parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11396839).

Now, this code works fine and the value of `test` is appended to the initial `page_view` and other following events:

```
gtag('config', 'G-1234567890', {
  test: false
});
```

Our site is a single page application (SPA) and at some point we want to update the parameter `test`.

The mentioned docs and also the [Global site tag API reference `set`](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#set) say, these parameters can be updated at any time. I found these two versions:

```
gtag('set', 'user_properties', {test: true});
gtag('set', {test: true});
```

Unfortunately, both won't work. I can get the updated parameter successfully using `get`:

```
gtag('get', 'G-1234567890', 'test', (test) => {
  console.log(test); // true
});
```

But the value is never updated for any subsequent request to Google Analytics and `test: false` is tracked all the time.

What are we doing wrong?